# Manually remove Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, 64-bit, 32-bit, visual-studio-2010

I used PC Mover when I upgraded to Windows 7 x64 from Windows XP 32 bit and it "helpfully" collected Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86) without any warning that it wasn't compatible with 64 bit.

Now it's stuck in and can't be uninstalled normally because the uninstaller is also the install/repair program, which detects it's running on 64bit then quits.

Can I trick the uninstall into going ahead and removing it? If not, what all do I need to remove from the Registry and which files do I need to delete?

Or if I just delete the files, CCleaner should find and delete the Registry info pointing to the deleted files.

Answer (score 2):

there's a microsoft uninstaller from microsoft.

maybe you should use this.

http://support.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/en